# Зачем нужны методы с двумя __ (например __ len__ или __del __) Можно ли обойтись без них?

Tags: python

```
a=5

def __del__(a):
    del(a)

__del__(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 5):

Ваш вопрос напоминает вопрос американского сенатора, когда в сенате должно было одобрить деньги для запуска новой метеостанции:

> «Зачем метеостанция? Когда я хочу знать прогноз погоды, я просто смотрю Интернет.»

Методы с двумя `__` подробно определяют - *индивидуально для каждого подходящего типа (класса),* что нужно сделать. Например `__len__()` для строки и `__len__()` для множества.

Затем возможно соответствующую функцию - например `len()` - использовать.

Дла типа `int` метод `__len__()` *не определен*, и так команда `len(7)` выводит *ошибку.*

Для типа `str` (строка) метод `__len__()` определен, и так
`len("что-то")` сделает `"что-то".__len__().`

**Ни не нужен Интернет для прогноза погоды, и не нужны функции соответствующие методам с двымя `__`.**

Но одно и другое нам упрощает жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит прочитать описание в [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) о методах с двойным подчеркиванием. Если кратко, то это специальные "магические" методы, которые выполняют какие то специфические действия или определяют какие то свойства.

Comment: `"выполняют какие то специфические действия или определяют какие то свойства"` – думаю, что так можно сказать про любые методы. Точнее сказать, что эти наименования встроены в Питон и используются операторами, что позволяет переопределять их поведение.